# Building tensorflow from source meets error: C++ compilation of rule '@jemalloc//:jemalloc' failed

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I'm attempting to build `tensorflow` from source on CentOS 6.2 using `gcc`. I updated `gcc` globally from 4.6.6 to 5.2.0, so that may be causing some problems. `Glibc` 2.17 is in a local directory, but the version of the system default `Glibc` is 2.12.

I get the following error:

> ERROR: /usr/local/app/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mqq/51871d27dfe77ebce0294c6560736a2c/external/jemalloc/BUILD:10:1: C++ compilation of rule '@jemalloc//:jemalloc' failed: gcc failed: error executing command 
>     (cd /usr/local/app/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mqq/51871d27dfe77ebce0294c6560736a2c/execroot/tensorflow && \
>     exec env - \
>       PATH=/data6/jimpan/env/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin:/data6/jimpan/env/python3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/jdk/jre/bin:/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin/:/usr/local/app/java/bin:/usr/local/app/bin \
>       PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
>       PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/data6/jimpan/env/python3/bin/python3 \
>       PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/data6/jimpan/env/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages \
>       TF_NEED_CUDA=0 \
>       TF_NEED_OPENCL=0 \
>     /usr/local/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -B/usr/local/bin -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections '-mcpu=native' -MD -MF bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/external/jemalloc/_objs/jemalloc/external/jemalloc/src/pages.pic.d -fPIC -iquote external/jemalloc -iquote bazel-out/local-py3-opt/genfiles/external/jemalloc -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/local-py3-opt/genfiles/external/bazel_tools -isystem external/jemalloc/include -isystem bazel-out/local-py3-opt/genfiles/external/jemalloc/include -isystem external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/gcc3 -O3 -funroll-loops -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -c external/jemalloc/src/pages.c -o bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/external/jemalloc/_objs/jemalloc/external/jemalloc/src/pages.pic.o): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
>   gcc: warning: '-mcpu=' is deprecated; use '-mtune=' or '-march=' instead
>   external/jemalloc/src/pages.c: In function 'je_pages_huge':
>   external/jemalloc/src/pages.c:203:30: error: 'MADV_HUGEPAGE' undeclared (first use in this function)
>     return (madvise(addr, size, MADV_HUGEPAGE) != 0);
>                                 ^
>   external/jemalloc/src/pages.c:203:30: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
>   external/jemalloc/src/pages.c: In function 'je_pages_nohuge':
>   external/jemalloc/src/pages.c:217:30: error: 'MADV_NOHUGEPAGE' undeclared (first use in this function)
>     return (madvise(addr, size, MADV_NOHUGEPAGE) != 0);
>                                 ^
>   external/jemalloc/src/pages.c: In function 'je_pages_huge':
>   external/jemalloc/src/pages.c:207:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
>    }
>    ^
>   external/jemalloc/src/pages.c: In function 'je_pages_nohuge':
>   external/jemalloc/src/pages.c:221:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
>    }
>    ^

`/usr/local/app` is the $HOME path of my system.

I guess the problem lies in `gcc`, but I'm stuck now and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What does `which gcc` says? And `gcc -version`?

Comment: @DamienMartin-guillerez 5.2.0

Comment: What about `which gcc`? `/usr/local/bin/gcc`?

Comment: Yes, `/usr/local/bin/gcc`

Comment: I am betting on a configuration issue for jemalloc. Would be interesting to get some people from the tensorflow team to look at it. The C++ configuration sounds correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that jemalloc's build is misconfigured (it's missing `MADV_NOHUGEPAGE` define). I found [this tensorflow issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7268) that is related.